# Unable to determine DKIM key length

Tags: email, dkim

I created a public and private key running `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`.

I then created a DNS entry `dkim._domainkey` of type `TXT` with this value:

```
v=dkim1; p=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
```

Now when I test it using https://protodave.com/tools/dkim-key-checker/ it says:

```
Unable to properly parse the public key string and determine key length or the key is invalid. Tip: Make sure there aren't any special charaters or newlines pasted into your key in the TXT record.
```

I just copy pasted the complete key out of the file that was generated by ssh-keygen. Any tips on how I can figure out what went wrong?

Comment: I think it is better to use 2048 or 1024 as key length. Also txt value should be enclosed in quotes("")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `openssl genrsa -out openssl.priv 1024` and `openssl rsa -in openssl.priv -pubout >openssl.pub` to generate the keys and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can and maybe should use keylength of 2048, it's in the DKIM spec.
That said, I heard of problems with mail servers hosted by AWS, insisting on 1024, but that was a few years back.

1. Create private key:

`$openssl genrsa -out dkim_private.pem 2048`

2. Pull out public key in der form, for encoding without LFs subsequently:

`$openssl rsa -in dkim_private.pem -pubout -outform der -out dkim_public.key`

3. Convert public key to base64 representation required:

`$openssl <dkim_public.key base64 -A >p_equals`

After this, the base64 encoded string in file p_equals is the string needed in your DNS TXT record (p=MI......AB ).